# Where is the M in MVC?

Tags: apache-flex, model-view-controller, design-patterns, cairngorm

The question I am going to ask was inspired by my latest work with the Flex platform (and some frameworks pretending to implement MVC), but I think it's general enough to involve people with various expertise.

For quite a lot of time I have followed the paradigms, proposed by frameworks like Cairngorm -

View, bound to properties of a singleton model, and dispatching events.
Events get caught by the front controller, and commands get executed as a result.
commands call services, get data, and supply the model.
The model implicitly updates the views through bindings.

It was all nice and sound until I got to the following data structure:

User
 has many followers (Users)
 follows many Users 
 has a bunch of photos
 follows many locations

Photo
 has many likers (User)
 has a location
 has a creator
 has many related photos

Location
 has many photos
 has many followers

Again, it would not be a problem to use the idea proposed by Cairngorm, for instance to have
a currentUser, currentLocation, and currentPhoto, and just bind to them.

The problem comes in the views themselves. I have a series of complex "page" views, which provide as drilled information, as one could imagine. For instance, the location page, shows a grid of latest/popular photos, a panel for for followers, and a map of based on the coordinates where those photos were taken. Here come the problems:

Obviously, for performance reasons, I cannot fetch all users that are following a particular location, or all photos a location could have. I have pre-fetched some, and others will supplied by the server on demand.

I want to drill-down staying on the same view, for example when clicking on a follower's avatar page, i should get a small grid of that user's photos, or sth. But i only have one currentUser in the model.

This leads to the question, why do i even need to bind to a central singleton model? Can't I just turn every view into a sort-of responder, i.e the view dispatches an even again, but this time the command instead of supplying the model, will supply the calling view directly.

There won't be any coupling because every view will implement IResponder. The command will require only an IResponder, which it will get from the Event it was called with.

The "model" as I see it, will play a different role. It will be more like a cache, a sort a global Dictionary for local storage, which will be checked by the command before it makes a request from the server. This way it may save some calls to the server, although, if the data is very sporadical, this same data will be fetched again and again together with other data. (I may have some user data in the cache, but in general I will call the server for a collection of follower data, regardless of whether some of it I might already have or not, for consistency )

Any feedback on these ideas will be appreciated

Comment: It's at the beginning. *rimshot*

Comment: Please refrain from rants here.

Comment: I am not ranting, I am just really curious

Comment: As curious as you are, you never really ask a question, and your 'rant' could be reduced to something more fundamental.

Comment: @J_A_X Whatever, you can just share your technical opinion ... and yeah I can't really ask questions, so take it as it is ... just like life

Comment: I tried to answer what I thought your question was; however I was torn between that and voting to close...

Comment: @user802232, Not with that attitude you can't.

Answer (score 1):

I think your actual question is this:

> This leads to the question, why do i
>   even need to bind to a central
>   singleton model?

You don't need to bind to a central singleton Model. In fact, many claim this approach is horrible and will cause performance issues.  Binding can be an expensive operation, so putting all the bindable values in one place can cause ripple effects in your app.

The fact that Cairngorm seems to push you in this direction is a common criticism for Cairngorm.  In Cairngorm's defense, I see no reason why--within the Cairngorm architecture--you can't have multiple "global data Singletons" if you want.  I'll refrain from regurgitating the arguments against Singletons in the first place.

Most post-Cairngorm frameworks can be seen as a response to Cairngorm and an attempt to do things differently.

Comment: Claim?  It's proven.  Singleton model *is* horrible :P

Comment: If it comes to the situation of having a model-per-view, why do I even need to abstract the data into separate model classes ? I could just leave it there, in the view itself. If my views implement IResponder, it would be pretty easy to make commands bring data directly from the services, to the views without knowing anything about the views themselves. I already see server-side as some sort of a model. Of course, I would agree that at least one singleton, for keeping general settings, would be nice to have.

Comment: Indeed.  Singletons are horrible.  Especially if you are someone who values unit testable code... singletons will get you every time. I should back up a bit... singletons are not bad... the Singleton pattern is bad.  Singleton lifetime is not, however, bad by nature.  Your main window is a singleton, for instance.  It is just when your class is responsible for it's own lifetime when you get a problem.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really an answer because the question isn't really a question.  However, if you want to look at 'MVC', you should stay *far far away* from Cairngorm since it implements probably the worst MVC pattern in all application frameworks for Flex.  One of best example (or worst depending how you look at it) of this is their use of the singleton model which [Theo already blogged about](http://blog.iconara.net/2008/04/13/architectural-atrocities-part-x-cairngorms-model-locator-pattern/).

You should look at [RobotLegs](http://www.robotlegs.org/) or [Parsley](http://www.spicefactory.org/parsley/) for a proper MVC architecture.  In my personal opinion of architecture, the 'model' is just another way to say 'data'.  It's just a class that holds data or state for your application.